# My sum function appears many times in my view

Tags: laravel

I wrote this code to display the sum  of amounts for every subaccount in account. 
But my sum appears for every invoice existing in the subaccount (amount is the cost, 5000).

View:

```
@foreach($invoices as $invoice)
@foreach($invoice->subaccount as $sub_accounts)
   <tr>
          @foreach($sub_accounts->subaccountinvoice as $sub_account)
              <td scope="row">{{$sub_account->sum('amount')}}</td>
           @endforeach
    </tr>                   
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Controller:

```
 public function dashboardSubaccount( $id )
    {
     $invoices = Account::with(['subaccount.subaccountinvoice'])->where('id',$id)->get();
    return view('Account.Dashboardsubaccount',['id'=>$id],compact('invoices')); 
     }
```

Any solution for that please ? 
[See the 5000 apprears two times.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCrTv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't loop your `subaccountinvoice`. Just call sum off the relationship:

```
$sub_accounts->subaccountinvoice->sum('amount')
```

Comment: Thank you sir, after, i want to display by account the sum of subaccount amout. 
I tried :
 @foreach($accounts as $account)
 {{$account->subaccount->subaccountinvoice->sum('amount')}} 
@endforeach
but this is not working